# Why doesn't this loop run for i = 1?

Tags: c++, loops, math

This loop is not running for i = 1
It should run 100 times but it's only running 99 times

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() { 
   double i = 0.01, j = 0.01;
   while(i<=1){
       cout<<i<<' ';
       i = i+j;
   } 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: don't use floating point numbers for loop conditions. Use an integer and then inside the loop `i = 0.01 * int_index;`

Answer (score -2):

Why don't start with i= 0.00, because 0.01 is already consuming first number. So 99 left.

Comment: If i = 0.00 the loop should run 101 times.